# can we call entity framework query with passing table value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is any way to pass the table name as a parameter and get the record  from db with make generalized function

```
string table = "tbl_Category";
int Id  = Class.getLastId(table);
```

Class.aspx

```
 public static int getLastId(string table)
    {

        int lastID = 0;
        using (HatnEntities context = new HatnEntities())
        {
            // Fetch Id of last record from table
                var result = (from c in context.tbl_Category.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id) select new { Id = c.Id }).FirstOrDefault();
                                                  ^
//any way to use table name from parameter value"+table+"


                if (result != null)
                {
                    lastID = Convert.ToInt32(result.Id);
                }
                obj.Id = lastID + 1;
                context.tbl_Category.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();

        }
        return status;
    }
```

Please let me know is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set() which would require that passing your table string parameter, you must get the Type from your assembly.

```
context.Set<TypeFromTableStringParameter>() ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would have to do if you just want to be able to access any table in EF:

```
public static int getLastId<T>()
    where T : PrimaryKey
{
    using (HatnEntities context = new HatnEntities())
    {
        // Fetch Id of last record from table
        var result = (from c in context.Set<T>().OrderByDescending(u => u.Id) select new { Id = c.Id }).FirstOrDefault();

        var lastID = 0;
        if (result != null)
        {
            lastID = Convert.ToInt32(result.Id);
        }
        obj.Id = lastID + 1;
        context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // not sure where this comes from?
    return status;
}

public abstract class PrimaryKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

All of you Entities would need to inherit (extend) `PrimaryKey` in order for you to `Select`, `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` (etc. etc.) based on the property `Id`.